# Completion handler in Model class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using the MVC for my app with Firebase. Right now in the Model class, I'd like to show a TableView with data retrieved from Firebase. There is one image associated with each cell. The problem now is that I cannot find a way to let the image show in the tableview. Downloading image is in the backend and I couldnt find a way to show it.

```
class List {
    let ref:DatabaseReference?
    var name : String
    var title : String
    var subtitle : String
    var time : String
    var puretime : Any
    var indexOfSelf : String
    lazy var photo : UIImage = UIImage()

    init(name: String, title: String, subtitle: String, time: String, puretime: Any, indexOfSelf: String, photo: UIImage) {
        self.ref = nil
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.time = time
        self.puretime = puretime
        self.indexOfSelf = indexOfSelf
        self.photo = photo
    }
    typealias CompletionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
    {
        guard
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
        let url = value["0"] as? String,
        let name = value["name"] as? String,
        let title = value["title"] as? String,
        let subtitle = value["subtitle"] as? String,
        let time = value["time"] as? String,
        let puretime = value["puretime"] as? Any,
        let indexOfSelf = value["indexOfSelf"] as? String
        else{
            return nil
        }

        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.time = time
        self.puretime = puretime
        self.indexOfSelf = indexOfSelf
        var image = UIImage()

    }
    var image = UIImage()
    func getImage(url:String, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        print("Doing something!")

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
        storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 2084 * 2084)
        { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error from downloading image is \(error)")

            } else {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                let flag = true
                completionHandler(flag)
            }

        }

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        return [
            "name": name,
            "title": title,
            "subtitle": subtitle,
            "time": time,
            "puretime": puretime,
            "indexOfSelf": indexOfSelf,
            "photo": photo
        ]
    }
}
```

Every other entity is working but the image. I'm not really sure how to use the completion in my case. SO could any one give me some suggestions please?
Thanks a lot

Comment: dont do this way. add a service handler class which has method with completionHandler(List) & from that class you can get array of all imges in your controller or in your viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service class and add a method as below (I also suggest creating List as a struct, not class.)

```
class YourServiceClass {
    func getItemList(completion: @escaping (Array< List >?,Error?)-> Void)
    {
      //call your get service and inside you service response
      //check for all your validation here  is a success then

        let listElms = arrayOfItems.compactMap(List.init)
        completion(listElms,nil)

    }
}
```

now from your viewController or viewModel call *getItemList*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. But I still have one question, where do I return the image to the List? If I don't init all the variables in init, it will complain that right?